# How do I specify another width for newly added divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm customizing the following script: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExpandingImageMenu/index_3.html

But instead of 6 divs (or the 6 guys in this case), I have 11 where the 4 last divs are opened with a custom navigation.

But I want to make the last 4 divs wider in size, if possible a variable size to fill up the right side of the content div.

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

```
/* get the item for the current */
var $item   = $menuItems.eq(current);
var $item2  = $menuItems + 7; /* i added this line */
```

&

```
/* if not just show it */
$item.css({width : '400px'})
$item2.css({width : '700px'}) /* and this one */
.find('.ei_image')
.css({left:'0px', opacity:1,});
```

Iv'e tried the  + + + + + css thingie but no luck for me, but I've uploaded the site... 
http://www.vernietig.be/depandoering/index2.html

Comment: what about using % for width ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using CSS to do this however, since your question clearly states 'in JavaScript', you can: 1. Calculate the width of the page - 2. Add up the width you <em>need</em> - 3. Use `$(".element").css("width", variable + "px");` to change the width of the last 4 elements. If you want, you can use `.animate({ width: variable + "px" });` instead. (I have given these examples in jQuery as it's quicker to type out)

Comment: CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MartyWallace/TpZ8B/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong at the moment. Firstly, the second line of code you added is actually part of some chained methods.

You don't need the first line of code you added.

After examining the script it looks like the `current` variable holds a zero based array index of the items in the trigger list. If it is not zero based you may need to change 6 to 7 in the code below (or to whatever is appropriate).

What I would suggest is:

```
/* if not just show it */
var itemWidth = current < 6 ? '400px' : '700px';
$item.css({width : itemWidth})
.find('.ei_image')
.css({left:'0px', opacity:1,});
```

**EDIT:** Update to include another line of code to change

Ok, You can also try changing this line:

```
itemParam   = (dir) ? {width : '400px'} : {width : '75px'},
```

to

```
itemParam   = (dir) ? current < 7 ? {width : '400px'} : {width : '700px'} : {width : '75px'},
```

**EDIT 2:** Update found a css change

In your css for `.ei_menu ul` remove `width: 1300px;`

And if you don't want the scrollbar to appear you can also remove `overflow: scroll;` from `.ei_descr2`.

**EDIT 3:** Update for last 4 divs to have variable width.

You can just change `.ei_descr2` where you tried `width: 100%;` to be `min-width: 300px;` that will cause the divs to have min-width of 300px and they will expand for more content if required. NOTE: you can change the `min-width` value to be whatever you like.

Comment: @ Sandor A, I've tried what U suggested but no luck... http://www.vernietig.be/depandoering/index2.html

Comment: its going in the right direction, but can't see myself getting this to work correctly :s

Comment: @mijncore Altering scripts is often harder than doing it yourself :) I updated my answer to include a css change for you also.

Comment: ok, seems more like it :) Already heaps of thanks Sandor!

Perhaps know how I can make the last 4 a variable width, already tried the 100% but that wouldn't work.

Comment: the things I "can" write in js are peanuts in comparisson to these fantastic scripts :)

Comment: about the overflow > it's me who has added the .ei_descr2 in addition to only .ei_descr in the original script. 
This because I had more content to add, but I'm going to look if a css scrollbar wouldn't be nicer. But those are things I can do myself :p

Comment: Glad to help and I hope the rest of your coding goes well :) I will update my answer shortly with variable width for the last 4 divs.

Comment: you're making my day :) :) :)

Comment: Updated my answer for variable witdh. This is just one way that I found. There may be others, and I am not 100% that min-width is supported by old versions of IE. Depending on your requirements you may want to test this in all targeted browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the css nth-child, check example in jsfiddle below

```
div{
    width:20px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin:1px;
    background:blue;
}
div:nth-child(n+7){
    width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k39B7/1/